# Google Spreadsheet conditional formatting script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to figure out how to use conditional formatting on a google spreadsheet similar to what you can do in excel via a formula.

I want cell A2 to change to Green if cell O2 has a value of "X" and this will be done on both columns all the way down.  I know this will require a script.

I ran across a link that is similar but i do not know how to adjust it to meet my needs.  Is this something that can be done?

Link:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a script you could use to do what you described:

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var columnO = sheet.getRange(2, 15, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var oValues = columnO.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {
    if (oValues[i][0] == 'X') {
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('green');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  I added another line so if the cell is blank, it changes back to white.

Comment: How do you USE this script once it is written?

Comment: @DanielWilliams Once you have the script saved in the script editor, you can run it in a few ways. The simplest is to press the Run button in the script editor (looks like a triangle/play button).  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_script_editor

Comment: @Jan Kleinert Exactly, your script still needs to be triggered. Edit listener can be added for whole sheet only, not for cells range (which may be performance degradation). Google Spreadsheet supports Conditional Formatting out of the box. The question was how to get the same functionality via script.

Comment: You can now add conditional formatting rules via a script (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57360312/3059685)

Answer (score 12):

In the new Google sheets, this no longer requires a script.

Instead, in conditional formatting, select the option "custom formula", and put in a value like `=O2="X"` - or indeed any expression that returns a boolean true/false value.

From what I can tell, the references listed in these custom scripts are a bit weird, and are applied as follows...

If it's a cell within your selected range, then it is changed to "the cell that's being highlighted".

If it's a cell outside your selected range, then it's changed to "that position, plus an offset the same as the offset from the current cell to the top left of the selected range".

That is, if your range was `A1:B2`, then the above would be the same as setting individual formatting on each cell as follows:

```
A1 =O2="X"
A2 =O3="X"
B1 =P2="X"
B2 =P3="X"
```

You can also specify fixed references, like `=$O$2="X"` - which will check the specific cell O2 for all cells in your selected range.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the weirdness of references with conditional formatting.  I was reaching for the API because that had me stumped.  Now I have full row-level control without needing scripts.

Answer (score 11):

With the latest [Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) you can programmatically add a conditional formatting rule to your sheet to do the highlighting.

You can add a custom formula rule that will set the background colour to green in column A where column O is "X" like this:

```js
function applyConditionalFormatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  var rangeToHighlight = sheet.getRange("A2:A");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=INDIRECT("R[0]C[14]", FALSE)="X"')
      .setBackground("green")
      .setRanges([rangeToHighlight])
      .build();

  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

The range (`"A2:A"`) that the conditional formatting applies to is [all the cells in the A column from row 2 downwards](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#expandable-1).

The custom formula is:

```
=INDIRECT("R[0]C[14]", FALSE)="X"
```

which means go 14 columns to the right of the selected range column and check if its value is "X".

Column O is 14 columns to the right of column A.

Comment: How would you adapt this to use conditional formatting so that any cell that has text formatted as a strikethrough is styled differently?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no _when_ methods in the [conditional-format-rule-builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) that can be used to match on cells containing a particular formatting. You would need to write a Google Application script like in the accepted answer to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 10):

**(Feb 2017)** As mentioned in another answer, Google Sheets now allows users to add [Conditional Formatting](http://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) directly from the user interface, whether it's on a desktop/laptop, Android or iOS devices.

Similarly, with [the Google Sheets API v4](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api) (and newer), developers can now write applications that CRUD conditional formatting rules. Check out the [guide](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/conditional-format) and [samples](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting) pages for more details as well as the [reference docs](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) (search for `{add,update,delete}ConditionalFormatRule`). The guide features this Python snippet (assuming a file ID of `SHEET_ID` and `SHEETS` as the API service endpoint):

```
myRange = {
    'sheetId': 0,
    'startRowIndex': 1,
    'endRowIndex': 11,
    'startColumnIndex': 0,
    'endColumnIndex': 4,
}

reqs = [
    {'addConditionalFormatRule': {
        'index': 0,
        'rule': {
            'ranges': [ myRange ],
            'booleanRule': {
                'format': {'textFormat': {'foregroundColor': {'red': 0.8}}}
                'condition': {
                    'type': 'CUSTOM_FORMULA',
                    'values':
                        [{'userEnteredValue': '=GT($D2,median($D$2:$D$11))'}]
                },
            },
        },
    }},
    {'addConditionalFormatRule': {
        'index': 0,
        'rule': {
            'ranges': [ myRange ],
            'booleanRule': {
                'format': {
                    'backgroundColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 0.4, 'blue': 0.4}
                },
                'condition': {
                    'type': 'CUSTOM_FORMULA',
                    'values':
                        [{'userEnteredValue': '=LT($D2,median($D$2:$D$11))'}]
                },
            },
        },
    }},
]

SHEETS.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEET_ID,
        body={'requests': reqs}).execute()
```

In addition to Python, Google APIs support a [variety of languages](http://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries), so you have options. Anyway, that code sample formats a Sheet (see image below) such that those younger than the median age are highlighted in light red while those over the median have their data colored in red font.

[image: Conditional formatting example]

---

PUBLIC SERVICE ANNOUNCEMENT

The latest Sheets API provides features not available in older releases, namely giving developers programmatic access to a Sheet as if you were using the user interface (conditional formatting[!], frozen rows, cell formatting, resizing rows/columns, adding pivot tables, creating charts, etc.).

If you're new to the API & want to see slightly longer, more general "real-world" examples of using the API, I've created various videos & related blog posts:

- [Migrating SQL data to a Sheet](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/introducing-google-sheets-api-v4.html) plus code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-new-google-sheets-api.html)
- [Formatting text using the Sheets API](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/formatting-cells-with-the-google-sheets-api.html) plus code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/09/formatting-cells-in-google-sheets-with.html)
- [Generating slides from spreadsheet data](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html) plus code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html)

As you can tell, the Sheets API is primarily for **document**-oriented functionality as described above, but to perform **file**-level access such as uploads & downloads, imports & exports (same as uploads & downloads but conversion to/from various formats), use the [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) instead. Examples of using the Drive API:

- Exporting a Google Sheet as CSV (blog [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html) only)
- "Poor man's plain text to PDF" converter (blog [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) only) (*)

(*) - TL;DR: upload plain text file to Drive, import/convert to Google Docs format, then export that Doc as PDF. Post above uses Drive API v2; this [follow-up post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/migrating-to-new-google-drive-api-v3.html) describes migrating it to Drive API v3, and here's a [video](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) combining both "poor man's converter" posts.