# Script to update Conditional Formatting ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, gs-conditional-formatting

I use conditional formatting in a Google Sheets to indicate whether a series of values satisfies a series of criteria (actuals versus goals for several metrics). From time to time, the goals change, and I have to update all the conditional formatting so that only current and future values are impacted by the change.

I would like to be able to specify a column reference to be replaced and a column reference to replace it with (e.g., replace references to column EK with FC in all conditional formatting on the sheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly replace the contents of the conditional formatting via script to reference a new column. What have you tried so far? Post your code. Here is an example of how to use script for CF:

[GAS-CF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653851/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-script)