# Google scripts if statement with conditional formatting on last row only

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to use a Google script to set a **cell in the last row only** of the 2nd column in a Google sheet to green color if it is:

**1.** `<0`, and

**2.** not equal to `#N/A`

**Partial preferred approach**

I have the following `if` statement (*without using a loop*):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()
if (sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 1) >0.00 && sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 1) !='#N/A') {
  sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 1).setFontColor('green');
}
```

However, this is not working. It is simply not assigning the color green to the font.

**Not the preferred approach**

I could do this *using a loop*, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10690603/4057186), and loop over all rows in the column one at a time:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()
var oValues = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastrow, 1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {
  if (oValues[i] >0.00) {
   sheet.getRange(i, 2, 1, 1).setFontColor('green');
  }
}
```

However, the disadvantage is that this approach is formatting all the rows in the column. I only need to format the last row.

Is there a way to avoid looping over all rows and just check if the last row meets **1.** and **2.** from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points :

- In your script, `sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 1) > 0.00` and `sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 1) !='#N/A'` mean the comparison with the range. When you want to compare the value of a cell, you can use `sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 1).getValue()`.
- The condition of `<0` and not equal to `#N/A` can be written by `if (value < 0 && value) {}`.
- The cell of last row of 2nd column can be written by `sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2)`.

  - In your case, you can also use `sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1)`.

The modified script which was reflected above is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2); // Last row of 2nd column
var value = range.getValue(); // Value of last row of 2nd column
if (value < 0 && value) { // <0 and not equal to #N/A
  // range.setBackground("green"); // This line give the background color of cell.
  range.setFontColor("green"); // This line give the font color of cell.
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: Thanks! I was completely missing the `.getValue()` part.