# AppScript: Conditional formatting of Google Sheet Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting

I have adapted a script which queries BigQuery and writes the results in a Google Sheet "report" in columns A:0. In column B there are some rows with the text "Total", where I would like to use a different background color. As the script which queries and writes the data deletes the existing data/rows every time, my "conditional formatting" does not work. Therefore I would like to use an AppScript, but do not manage to adapt examples I found.

What should the app script do?
If a cell in column B contains "Total" it should set the background color for the row (range A:0) to green.

I tried something like this, but as I know very little of AppScript it is probably not very close to the solution ;-)

```
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Report');
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, numCols);
      var customFormulaString = "=$B1='Total'";
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .whenFormulaSatisfied(customFormulaString) 
          .setBackground("green")
          .setRanges([range])
          .build();        
      var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
      rules.push(rule);
      sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you use the script to set up conditional formatting? Why not just write the background immediately with the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

Following what Cooper suggested, here is what it meant:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),15).getDisplayValues(); 
  console.log(range);
  range.map((x,i) => x[1].toLocaleLowerCase().includes('total') ? sheet.getRange('A' + (i + 1) + ':O' + (i + 1)).setBackgroundRGB(0,255,0) : x);
}
```

**Sample:**

[image]

Comment: Great thank you very much, Century Tuna. That did the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this depending on your [coding preference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) like what is discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653851/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-script/57360312#57360312).

I see a couple of rows from your code that needs to be adjusted, please try:

```
// Set the row where the string "Total" appeared 
var range = sheet.getRange("A" + numRows + ":O" + numRows);
// Check if the value of Column B is "Total"
var customFormulaString = '=INDIRECT("R[0]C[1]", FALSE)="Total"';
```

Learn more about INDIRECT from this [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en#).

Comment: Thanks, Mel. As the first solution worked, I did not try your proposal. But I understand what you mean and sure will try if I have a similar question :-)

Comment: @Albrecht, no worries. Just helping out our community. :)